# Need one chart with data not compared to each other

Tags: reporting-services, charts

Ok - I'm rewording my question in hopes of getting as response. I (with help from a co-worker) have created the following SQL query that pulls the EXACT results that I need to appear in an SSRS chart:

```
 select 
 (SELECT  pfsp.SavingsGoal
 FROM     Projects AS p INNER JOIN
                     Projects_PerformanceServicesProject AS pfsp ON p.Id = pfsp.Id INNER JOIN
                     ProjectSavingsGoalTypes AS gt ON pfsp.ProjectSavingsGoalType_Id = gt.Id
 WHERE        (p.Id = @Project_ID)) as SavingsGoal,
 (SELECT  
 Sum(identifiedSum)
 FROM  #Yaks where UPPER(name) = 'DECLINED'
 GROUP BY name)as IdentifiedDeclined,
 (SELECT 
 Sum(identifiedSum)
 FROM #Yaks) as identifiedTotal,
 (SELECT 
 Sum(implementableSum) 
 FROM            #Yaks where upper(name) = 'APPROVED'
 GROUP BY name) as implementableSavingsApproved,
 (SELECT 
 Sum(implementedSum)
 FROM            #Yaks 
 ) as implementedSavingsTotal
```

What the chart should ultimately look like (generally speaking):

http://i1365.photobucket.com/albums/r745/twarden11/chart_mockup_zps22cfdbf3.png

Telling you everything I've tried would take all my characters, and would be good for a laugh, and that's about it. It was also be futile, as I am an extreme novice (this is my first time to build a chart - ever, please be clear and speak in non-technical terms when possible), and my efforts I can assure had nothing to do with what I need to be trying.

So what I need are plain instructions on how to turn this query into the table graphic that I've included. I can't express how desperate I am at this point. My co-worker said it would be easier to simply pull the exact data that I need in the query, but never told me how to convert the query to a chart.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I seriously would appreciate some help today if possible. Please help.

Comment: Try changing the chart type to something other than stacked bar?

Comment: I've tried several kinds of charts. All of them force me to compare all of the data I want to each other. I just want one column per SELECT, and use the identifiedSum + 1000 as the high number on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would redesign the SQL query to return 2 columns and 5 rows.  The 1st column would describe the category e.g. Goal, Identified etc.  The 2nd column would present the $ values.

This would probably require a series of SELECT ... UNION ALL ... clauses, one for each of the 5 rows required.

Then I would add the 1st column to the chart as the Category Group, and the 2nd column as the Values (series).